# Get rid of file name and date in VScode markdown

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

I am very new to markdown. I use VScode editor with Markdown All in One and Markdown PDF extensions.

Let's say I open test.md file and write the following text

```
### This is my first markdown text

Hello
```

When I export the text into pdf, using `Ctrl+Shift+P - markdown-pdf: Export (pdf)`, I get the following output:

[image]

The question is, how do I get rid of the name and the date in the upper part of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to `Markdown-Pdf`'s README [doc](https://github.com/yzane/vscode-markdown-pdf),in the chapter `Options`,disable the `markdown-pdf.displayHeaderFoote` may solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can get rid of the `name and the date` in the upper part of the page by `disable` the option of `markdown-pdf.displayHeaderFoote`

If you disable the option, the page number will not display as well. Therefore, if you want to keep the footer or something as well, or you want to change the infomation of the header or footer. You should change the code in option `markdown-pdf:header template` and `markdown-pdf:footer template`

For example: use these code`<div style="font-size: 9px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: 1cm; ">%%ISO-DATE%%</div>` to substitue the default code in `markdown-pdf:header template`, the final pdf will not contain the filename but keep date